# Why lm doesn't work on a modified data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

When I change my data.frame I get an error and can't do the lm:

```
observation.not.i = area[-i, ]
fit.new.observation = lm(farm ~ land, data = observation.not.i)
```

Error is

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'land' not found
```

I am using this in jackknife procedure as in the following:

```
r.jack = c(rep(0, 50))
y.hat = c(rep(0, 50))
for (i in 1:50) {
    observation.not.i = area[-i, ]
    fit.new.observation = lm(farm ~ land, data = observation.not.i)
    y.hat[i] = predict(fit.new.observation, data.frame(land.area=area[i, 3]))
    r.jack[i] = area[i, 2] - y.hat[i]
}
```

However when I just run `fit=lm(farm~land,data=area)` it works fine. Please let me know if you are aware of the cause of the problem.

Comment: You need to provide `newdata` a data frame with variables containing all the variables on RHS of the formula, but you are providing a variable `land.area`, hence `land` is not found in `newdata`. Why not `predict(fit.new.observation, newdata = area[i, , drop = FALSE])`?

Comment: Hi Gavin, this worked the same as the answer provided by user3114046 . Thanks. I understand that one better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y.hat[i] = predict(fit.new.observation, data.frame(land.area=area[i, 3]))
```

The `fit.new.observation` model is expecting a column called `land` in the `newdata` argument of `predict`, but the column is called `land.area`.

Comment: predict(fit.new.observation, data.frame(land=area[i, 3]))